# .htacces file for WordPress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am working on an `.htaccess` file for a WordPress site and want to allow certain IP addresses to see parts of the site, while disallowing access to wp-login.php. Is my code correct?

```
ErrorDocument 500 /home/cyberstu/public_html/post.php?p=346
ErrorDocument 404 /home/cyberstu/public_html/post.php?p=346
ErrorDocument 403 /home/cyberstu/public_html/post.php?p=346
ErrorDocument 301 /home/cyberstu/public_html/post.php?p=346

<FilesMatch "^wp-login\.php$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from myipaddress
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

The problem I have is the login uses a plugin that uses javascript, it is  called white label login plugin, very nice, but it somehow bypasses the wp-login.php file, how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Replace xx.xxx.xx.xx with your IP address.

```
<Files wp-login.php>
        order deny,allow
        Deny from all

# IP address
allow from xx.xxx.xx.xx

</Files>
```

Also

To allow access from a single IP address, replace 123.123.123.123 with your own IP address:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-login\.php(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?wp-admin$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123.123.123.123$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=403,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Many thanks Noman, I did try something like this, but i`ll try the code this morning and certianly get back to you, thank you again for your help.

Comment: Hi Noman, i tried both and they work when I use the normal wp-login.php but i`m using a modal login, you can see here www.cyberstudy.co.uk

Comment: The problem I have is how to block the modal login from being accessed it somehow bypasses the normal wordpress wp-login.php file so the htaccess wont work.

Comment: Would you be able to view the javascript for this Noman ? I cant see how to block that file using htaccess. many thanks Neil

Comment: @NeilWilliams sorry for late reply , is your problem solved ? and if you want to block modal JS then you to mention JS file name.

Comment: @NeilWilliams you plugin by pass the htaccess security. create a new `.htaccess` file with above code and the `ip address` and upload in `wp-admin` folder , it may block access to defined `ips`

Comment: I tried this in the wp-admin but doesnt seem to block, i`ll try a few different variations, many thanks for your help. i`ll get back to you if I find a fix.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for your help, you definitely guided me in the right direction, this solved it, first by stopping access to the plugin, this then opened up wp-login.php

Here is the .htaccess file

```js
ErrorDocument 403 /path/to/your/error/page/here

 

 

 

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

 

RewriteEngine on

 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)white-label-login(.*)$ [OR]

 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)wp-login\.php(.*)$

 

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^youripaddresshere$

 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=403,L]

 

</IfModule>

 

# BEGIN WordPress

 

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

 

RewriteEngine On

 

RewriteBase /

 

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

 

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

 

</IfModule>
```